# Help with Excel Power View and SharePoint

Tags: powerview

Sharepoint Online (O365 E3 Plan) and Excel 2013.

Hi, I created Power View in excel using data from our CRM. I exported data from our CRM, created a PowerPivot table from the data, run a few functions and from there created a Power View Sheet.
From there I was able to display the Power View sheet on SharePoint using Excel Services web part.

The challenge that I am having is I would like to automatically filter the data based on the user that is logged in. Also it is important that the user not be able to change the filters and see other users data.

Is this possible?

I have already tried using Current User Filter and passing the user information, but for the life of I can't figure out how to have the power view accept it as a filter.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload an Excel PowerPivot file to SharePoint it automatically creates a Tabular database in the background.  As far as I know, there is no way to just apply row level permissions as is, but you can copy the Tabular database and then apply permissions structures in there as needed.

Comment: That is correct, I have been able to see specific tables and single them out based on the name of the table, but not Power Views.  The only time I can see a Power View is based on the default view.  But to single out a specific Power View is where I am having an issue

Comment: Ah ok - that is slightly different.  Once you have the PowerPivot uploaded then you can create additional Power Views through the browser which can be saved as files.  You could use multiple libraries with different permissions on them to save individual Power Views?

Comment: I see what you are saying, it seems like this might be the only way.